# how can I use await/async to get this data?

Tags: angular

I'm calling a service from a component. The service calls an external service which returns data asyncronously. My component needs to know when the data is returned in order to get a handle to the data.  I think I've done something like this with async/await in the past but I seem to be forgetting something in the example below.  Any idea what the gap is here?:

my.component.ts:

```
constructor(private afdb: AngularFireDatabase,  private ts: TestService)
{
    this._ts = ts;
    this._afdb = afdb;
    this.loadData();
}

async loadData()
{
    this._vms = new TestService(this._afdb);        
    this.testData = await this._ts.getTestData();
}
```

test.service.ts:

```
public getTestData()
{
    this._afdb.list('TestData').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
    }).subscribe(items => {
        return items;
    }); 
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: I'm trying to ensure that the data is returned from the service before it gets set to the member variable on the component but my code above isn't doing this

Comment: What is happening then? Your question is very unclear, that's why it's gotten 4 downvotes so far.

Comment: this is a common scenario, right?  I need to delegate my external service calls into an ng service.  the service call returns data asyncronously but I need to ensure that my component has a handle to the returned data before attempting to set the data to a component member var

Comment: looks like subscribing to an observable may be another way to do this if someone can provide some insight

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways you can go about this .

1. Subscribe to the service and render the component once the data is available using ngIf

   this.yourService.yourFunction.subscribe(value=>{
   this.displayValue = value;
   this.displayValueAvailable = true;
   })

and in the templete you can do

```
<div *ngIf="displayValueAvailable"></div>
```

2. You can use async pipe
   You can let the template know that the data is async and render when the data is available using async pipe.
   You can see the documentation here https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe
3. Set the component value to empty ie. if it is an array

   ar: Array = [];

and in the subscribe function set the value of this array. Once the value is available, angular change detection should take care of the rest :) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the async pipe, which you use in your template. If a property in your component class is an observable, you can add that property to the component's template with the async pipe.

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe